# SearchKit is not displaying contacts with a specific membership type

Tags: civimember, searchkit

I am looking for a way to build a SearchKit report that displays all contacts with a specific membership type. My initial search was based on the Contacts table with (optional) Contact Membership Types. This didn't work because that table seems to only look at the organization associated with the membership. The results only rendered the organization, not the individuals holding the membership.

My next thought was to add contacts with those memberships to a static group and then have my SearchKit report query on group members. This got me the list of contacts that I wanted. However, I added a column to the SearchKit to display a list of Membership Types for each contact and that remains empty since SearchKit seems to only be looking at the related organization.

We are on D7 CiviCRM 5.41.2. Is this something that is corrected with a later update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set up a quick searchkit search on the dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

with these parameters

[image: screenshot of membership search settings]

And got these results

[image: searchkit results]

So I think searchkit will do what you want

But it does change between versions of civi

the demo site is now running 5.54- so yeah upgrade before you give up on searchkit